# Wyse S50 RDP Failure

Tags: rdp, terminal, thin-client

**Background:**
I've got a LAN with about 6 Wyse S10 terminals, these terminals are serviced by a Microsoft 2008 R2 server with Remote Desktop Services enabled and 10 CALs assigned.

I needed another terminal for a new station.  I ordered, what appeared to be, a used identical terminal.  It is the same model being an SX0, but the PROD ID is S50 as opposed to the S10 terminals I already have.  No biggie.

**Terminal Specs:**
Firmware version on the S10 terminals is 6.5.0_22.  Firmware version on the new S50 terminal is 6.5.0.

**Problem:** 
The new terminal will not connect to the terminal host.  It will connect to every other server on my LAN that I have tried.  Both Server 2008 and Server 2003 hosts are successful.

I have tried troubleshooting this by changing every connection setting on the S50 that I can find to no avail.  The closest I can get is a a brief RDP window appearance and then it quickly disappears.  Sometimes I get a warning dialog box that says 'Network is down, do you want to exit Remote Desktop?'

**Question:**
Does anyone have any ideas why it simply will not connect to the terminal services host?

**Additional Info:**
The only thing I've found in the server log was a single instance of this error from the TermDD source:
"The RDP protocol component "DATA ENCRYPTION" detected an error in the protocol stream and has disconnected the client."

I tried toggling the connection encryption to no avail, but it should be irrelevant as the other terminals appear to be using the same encryption settings.

Thanks in advance.